# How to get pump.io OAuth consumer key?

Tags: php, oauth

I'm working on a web application with php and need to communicate with pump.io like servers through activity stream API. However to  perform subsequent operations i need to authenticate via OAuth and it needs OAuth consumer key, problem is that I couldn't find any procedure on pump.io servers to generate that key, at least I'm not aware of such a thing. Anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a full expert of pump.io, but there is a model called **accesstoken**. (https://github.com/e14n/pump.io/blob/master/lib/model/accesstoken.js)

I seems to have a method where a random token is generated. (lines 65-67)

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of pump.io.

Pump.io supports dynamic client registration. The documents are here:

http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am developing pump.io on my iOS app. We have created server in backend. I am able to get lists (favorites, followers) from users already registered using browser not from in iOS app. But while registration, i got some error. Is their any authentication we needed?   Actually the URL which i used is: https://hostname/api/users/ and used JSON Object to add parameters
 @"nickname" : @"sam123",
 @"password" : @“sam123",                                    @“email" : @“sam123@sam123.com”

I would like to register automatically a user from m iOS app using the api. What are the PATH, params ?  In pump.io wiki -> API.md they provided us:  User registration  There is a collection of all users at the endpoint /api/users. To create a new user, POST a user representation (see below) to the list. You can also get the latest registered users by GETting the collection.  The JSON object representing the user has the following properties:  nickname: The user's nickname. 1-64 characters, including only ASCII capital and lowercase letters and numbers as well as "-", ".", and "_". The nickname is immutable and unique per server; it can't be changed. password: The plain-text password. This isn't returned when you GET the user object, but you have to provide it when registering or updating the user. profile: a "person" object. This is created automatically when you create a new user; don't try to add it yourself. Don't update this directly; update the person through its object endpoint

Anyone have ever integrated in iOS registration/login process.